# GTK3: Multiple event loops within one application

Tags: gtk3

I'm not certain whether it is possible to have more than one event loop within a GTK3 application. The naive approach by calling `gtk_application_new()`/`g_application_run()` from different threads fails.

It's needed for a plug-in system where one plug-in doesn't know whether another plug-in has already started the event loop. There's a prototype application demonstrating (on MSYS2) that it's possible within Windows but the naive approach within GTK3 as soon as the second event loop is started by `g_application_run()` fails with

> ```
> (loop2.exe:11084): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:47:26.573: g_application_run: assertion 'acquired_context' failed
> ```

I'm convinced that it should be possible. What I'm missing?

```
snprintf(id,(sizeof id)-1,"net.sourceforge.pbelkner%d",loop->id);
app=gtk_application_new(id,G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
g_signal_connect(app,"activate",G_CALLBACK(loop_activate),NULL);
g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app),0,NULL);
g_object_unref(app);
```

Comment: "from different threads" should better read "from dedicated threads".

Comment: We've managed to publish the above discussed source code on an external page: http://home.snafu.de/pbelkner/loops.html.

Comment: was this problem solved somehow?